# Stack around the variable 'x' was corrupted

Tags: c

Write a program that asks the user to input seven integer numbers. The program must use an array
to store these values.
After the user inputs all the values, the program must print out the contents of each array element
in the style shown below.
Finally the program must sum the seven elements and print out the resulting sum.

My program does exactly what it is meant to, however, once it is completed I get the "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'integer' was corrupted". I've looked through all my notes and can't figure out why, sorry if this is very basic, I am just learning how to program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int integer[6];

    printf("Please enter seven integers:\n");

    printf("\nInput 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &integer[0]);

    printf("Input 2: ");
    scanf("%d", &integer[1]);

    printf("Input 3: ");
    scanf("%d", &integer[2]);

    printf("Input 4: ");
    scanf("%d", &integer[3]);

    printf("Input 5: ");
    scanf("%d", &integer[4]);

    printf("Input 6: ");
    scanf("%d", &integer[5]);

    printf("Input 7: ");
    scanf("%d", &integer[6]);

    printf("\nArray input was: { %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d }\n", integer[0], integer[1], integer[2], integer[3], integer[4], integer[5], integer[6]);

    int sum = integer[0] + integer[1] + integer[2] + integer[3] + integer[4] + integer[5] + integer[6];

    printf("\nThe sum of the array elements is: %d", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

So the output is as expected, however I cant figure out why the variable is corrupted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array has only six (6) elements, but you read seven (7), thus corrupting the memory beyond the allocated array. Change the array definition to:

```
int integer[7];
```

Remember that C counts from zero, whereas the number in the brackets in array definition is the number of elements, aka the size of the array. So valid indices of `int integer[6]` would be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, **NOT** including 6.

Comment: I feel silly now, thanks a lot mate I really appreciate it.